# "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 3 has experienced an internal error. "

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 3 and my user interface is not stable especially the menu bar keeps on triggering and sends me this message "Sorry, Ubuntu 16.04 has experienced an internal error. If you notice further problem, try restarting the computer "How can this be solved?

Comment: do a  sudo apt update and update whole system, might be a minor bug. that dialog box is of Apport you can google how to turn it off in Ubuntu.